# How do I access this Javascript mysql error object (Nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

More details below, but the question is **is the below a valid javascript object and how do I access that first array type thing**

```
{ [some-text-here-without-quotes] key1: 'text', key2: 1, key3: '23000', key4: 0 }
```

Building an app with Nodejs, Express and MySQL.
I have decided to use the 'mysql' library found in NPM at this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql.

While testing I purposely created a duplicate entry condition that violated a unique constraint because I wanted to see what the returned error object looks like.

When I console.log(error) from the query the following is what prints:

```
{ [Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'abcdefg' for key 'token_UNIQUE'] code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY', errno: 1062, sqlState: '23000', index: 0 }
```

I must be missing something obvious. But I cannot seem to access the data in that first array looking thing. The part of the object that starts  with *[Error:* and ends with *'token_UNIQUE']*

**How do I access that part of the object?**

*(also, first I thought it was an improperly formatted object string or something buggy from the mysql library but underscore.js says it is an object*

```
_.isObject(error); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

got the exact same problem, and i still dont understand what that particular syntax means..
however, i managed to access this part of the object by force casting it into a string, by merely concatenating it to a string contant :

```
if (error) {    
    error.isError=1
    errmsg=" "+error   <---- cast to string here
    error.msg=errmsg;  <---- then back into the object as a tring
    response.end(JSON.stringify(error));
    db.end();
    console.log("<-"+error)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Object.keys(err)
```

This will give you the list of keys that are contained in the `err` object. From that, you can pick the keys of your intereste. (or) you can use,

```
console.dir(err)
```

to print the object in a formatted way.

Comment: If you look closely at my first code snippet, you will see that there is no commma after the _array-thingy_. That is what is perplexing me. When I do a `console.log(Object.keys(error));` it prints `[ 'code', 'errno', 'sqlState', 'index' ]` Notice that there is no reference to that _array-thingy_.

Comment: that is a message passed from where the error is thrown like new Error([Error: %s: Duplicate entry 'abcdefg' for key %s] ).

Comment: Hmmm I don't think we are connecting on my question. I have added some details hoping that it might help explain better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

maybe the answer is a little bit late, I encountered this problem yesterday. but the solution is simple, just use toString()

error.toString()

error.message maybe a formal way

both methods above returning the same output

Comment: This is actually a good and useful answer. Give them some points!

Comment: thanks for trying it, actually I found out another way. using error.message will get the same output.